# How to call a @future method from Batch Apex?

Tags: batch

Can anyone please give me an example or an idea on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your exact question is, but this video is pretty much the current SFDC async apex bible, as far as I know. Covers @future, batch, and queueable, as well as ways to chain them together in different ways.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZqqiIg_mynY